# Newline in a for loop

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

How can i make a newline in a for loop in bash? I've tried `echo -e` but its not working. When i am opening a log file everything is on a single line.

```
for i in */ ; do
    sitefolder="$HOME/domains/${i%%/}/public_html"
    if [ -d "$sitefolder" ]; then
        echo -e "\nBackup of ${i%%/} successfull" >> $logs/backups.log
    fi
done
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Not sure, but try `\r\n` (Carriage Return + Newline) instead of just `\n` (Newline).

Comment: I will try in a few mins :) will tell you if it worked, thanks

Comment: Nice, I'll throw it in as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line:

`echo -e "\nBackup of ${i%%/} successfull" >> $logs/backups.log`

Replace the Newline (`\n`) with a Carriage Return + Newline (`\r\n`) to ensure that both are happening.

For more info, perhaps check out this Programmers.stackexchange.com question: [Difference between '\n' and '\r\n'](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n), and this StackOverflow question: [Historical reason behind different line ending at different platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419291/historical-reason-behind-different-line-ending-at-different-platforms)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CTRL` + `V` together then press `J` to embed a newline(s) in the echo statement.

On Unix and Linux systems `CTRL + V` indicates that the character that follows is interpreted as a control character.

Comment: I have to use Vi editor to make that?

Comment: not necessarily - it's not vi specific. You can do the same in bash.

Comment: Well i am editing my script.sh file using PhpStorm. How can i do that there? :)

Comment: Don't know about phpStorm - you need to embed a CTRL+J character though.

Comment: Not working. Maybe it should work under linux? I am on windows 8.1

Comment: bash on windows so you using cygwin?

Comment: nope, i am working on my remote centos6 webserver via SSH.

Comment: ok. Windows is not relevant here. You are logged onto a linux machine. Two possibilities are: use vi to embed the newline, or look up help for phpStorm editor to find how to embed CTRL+j.

Answer (score 0):

There are different versions of the `echo` command out there and different versions can handle their optional arguments differently. Using any optional arguments with `echo` is not portable. The simplest solution is to add another `echo`, like this:

```
echo >> $logs/backups.log
echo "Backup of ${i%%/} successful" >> $logs/backups.log
```

or like this:

```
{
echo
echo "Backup of ${i%%/} successful"
} >> $logs/backups.log
```

Alternatively, you could use `printf` instead of `echo`, which is preferred these days at least for portability.

```
printf "\nBackup of ${i%%/} successful\n" >> $logs/backups.log
```

All of those solutions will put newlines between each line, as is the Unix convention. Some Windows editors understand single newlines to mean end-of-line. Others, such as Notepad, do not and will display your file as a single line.

One solution to that problem is again to use `printf`.

```
printf "\r\nBackup of ${i%%/} successful\r\n" >> $logs/backups.log
```

Contrary to other recommendations, it is best not to try to embed literal control characters within `echo` or `printf` commands. They are difficult to see, difficult to edit, and mess up the display of your script if you just `cat` it.

Note in all of the above I have assumed that you wanted a line break both before and after your "successful" note. If that wasn't your intent, modify those commands accordingly.